# ngf-select select menu from dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to select menu from drop down but my `ngf-select` is not working.

Show 2 images to compare

```
  <form ng-submit="submitImgs()">
    <div>
      <!-- <div>
        <div ng-repeat="img in files">
          <img ngf-thumbnail="image" style="width: 50%; height: 50%"/><br />
        </div>
      </div> -->
      <button class="btn btn-info" ngf-select ng-model="files" ngf-multiple="true" ngf-capture="capture" ngf-resize="{width: 500}">
        Select Files
      </button>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">COMPARE</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I think I included all cdns that are required for ngf-select work

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.file-upload/12.2.9/ng-file-upload-all.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.file-upload/12.2.9/ng-file-upload-shim.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.file-upload/12.2.9/ng-file-upload.js"></script>
```

Does anyone knows what is going on here?

Comment: What's the problem? Is the file selection window not opening? or is it opening, but no function is called? Since you didn't pass a function to ngf-select (e.g ngf-select = "upload($file)" ), i'm assuming you $watch your files variable.....are you doing that?